# iPod Icon Images

Tags: macos, mac, icons, ipod

Does anyone know of a place where I can get high-quality iPod icons (I'm specifically looking for a 5G iPod). I want to use it to make a custom volume icon for an iPod I'm using as a bus-powered drive. It would preferably be 512x512 or as high a resolution as possible. Shouldn't iTunes have those resources sitting around somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one](http://corey-grandy.deviantart.com/art/iPod-Video-5G-RC2-Leopard-110698926), [and another](http://pinky-von-pout.deviantart.com/art/iPod-5G-Redrawn-Preview-80803517), [and another](http://pinky-von-pout.deviantart.com/art/iPod-5G-74174553), [and another](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/aire-icons-by-gakuseisean/iPod-5G-icon.html), but this one maxes out at 256x256

Why don't you just find a high res picture of an iPod 5G and turn it into an icon?

Comment: It's tough finding a high-quality one (i.e. one that Apple would post to its site, not a dimly lit mess of a Flickr post). The second one you posted will work after I turn it white. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [Icon Factory](http://iconfactory.com/freeware/preview?type=show&id=236) released some free icons for the iPod - they are however the 4G and only at 128x128. (Mac OS X at the time of release of those icons did not support icons larger than 128x128)

Comment: That's so close... But I'm too anal to allow an inaccurate image :-(